# Loop through data and load data from csv file

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, csv

I'm having difficulty looping through this 2 sets of data. With 1 set of data it works but now I want to add more 3 or 4 . Also I want to load the data from a local csv file that I will upload and to update the data I will save the file and overwrite it.  http://jsfiddle.net/kmc3ohab/7/

```js
var data = {
    "box1": {
        "bar1": "80%",
        "bar2": "60%",
        "bar3": "40%",
        "bar4": "50%",
        "total": "60%",
    },
     "box2": {
        "bar1": "80%",
        "bar2": "60%",
        "bar3": "40%",
        "bar4": "50%",
        "total": "80%",
    },
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".score-text").html(data.box1.total);
    $(".data").each(function( index, value ) {
        width = eval('data.box1.bar' + (index+1));
        value.innerText = width;
        value.style.width = width;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
 background: #efefef;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 0px;
 text-align: center;
}

h2 {
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', serif;
 color: #b71f38;
 font-weight: 300;
 margin: 0px;
}

h3 {
 font-family: 'Noto Sans', serif;
 color: #444444;
 font-weight: 200;
 margin: 0px;
}

#colLeft {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}

#colRight {
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
}

#row {
 background: #e2e2e2;
 width: auto;
 height: 230px;
 margin: 15px;
 border-radius: 5px;
}

#insideColLeft {
 width: 30%;
 float: left;
}

#insideColRight {
 width: 69%;
 float: right;
 padding-top: 8px;
 padding-right: 5px;
}

.circle {
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 150px;
 position: relative;
 background: #b71f38;
}

.circle:before {
 content: "";
 display: block;
 padding-top: 100%;
}

.circle-inner {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 text-align: center;
}

.score-text {
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 height: 1em;
 line-height: 1em;
 font-size: 30px;
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 color: #ffffff;
}

.date {
 font-family: 'Fjalla One', sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 color: #333333;
}

ul.graph {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}
 
ul.graph li {
 margin: 10px;
 height: 25px;
 background: #ccc;
 color: #fff;
}
 
ul.graph li.data {
 background: #f4ebb8;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <h3>Subtitle</h3>
      <div id="insideColLeft">
        <div class="circle">
          <div class="circle-inner">
            <div class="score-text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div id="insideColRight">
        <ul class="graph">
          <li class="data">bar 1</li>
          <li class="data">bar 2</li>
          <li class="data">bar 3</li>
          <li class="data">bar 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
<div id="row">
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <h3>Subtitle</h3>
      <div id="insideColLeft">
        <div class="circle">
          <div class="circle-inner">
            <div class="score-text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
      <div id="insideColRight">
        <ul class="graph">
          <li class="data">bar 1</li>
          <li class="data">bar 2</li>
          <li class="data">bar 3</li>
          <li class="data">bar 4</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You should avoid the use of `eval` and instead try to use an `array of object` because you are constraining your possibilities with your current approach.

Comment: How do I change it from eval to array of objects?

Comment: For example: `var data = { boxes: [{
        "bar1": "80%",
        "bar2": "60%",
        "bar3": "40%",
        "bar4": "50%",
        "total": "60%",
    },{
        "bar1": "80%",
        "bar2": "60%",
        "bar3": "40%",
        "bar4": "50%",
        "total": "60%",
    }]}` This way you can have an infinite number of boxes, you just don't have unique names anymore.

Comment: @bash.d No need for that []-arrays. Text-based index-access is also possible.

Comment: @JosephZammit - I've updated my answer to show you one possible way to avoid eval. (Remember: eval() == evil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care of the box-index in your document-ready-function. In your code there is a fix "box1" but the index of .data will go up to 7. So divide the index by 4 and then you can calculate the box-indexes. You also have to loop over your score-text-elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".score-text").each(function( index, value ) { 
       value.innerText = data['box'+(index+1)].total;
   });

   $(".data").each(function( index, value ) {  
       var boxIndex = Math.floor(index/4);
       width = data['box'+(boxIndex+1)]['bar'+(index+1-boxIndex*4)];
       value.innerText = width;
       value.style.width = width;
   });
});
```

I've updates your example, too. 
http://jsfiddle.net/kmc3ohab/11/